# bulk update springboot jpa

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, bulkupdate

I need to update single column(status) of more than 1000-2000 transactions at once.The value to be updated is same e.g "PROCESSED" for all the rows. I don't want to iterate on my list and update but looking for a bulk update in jpa itself. I also want to avoid explicit use of entity manager.

Comment: *I need to update single column(status) of more that 1000-2000 transactions* Update with what value? the same for all rows to be updated?

Comment: Does "1000-2000 transactions" to be updated "at once" may be filtered by one WHERE condition? Or this is all rows in a table? or you want to update all rows by chunks of 1000-2000 rows per chunk?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work, with standard Spring-boot JPA:

```
public interface WidgetRepository extends CrudRepository<Widget, Long> {
    @Override
    List<Widget> findAll();

    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true)
    @Query("update Widget w set w.status = :status where w in :widgets")
    void setStatus(@Param("status") String status, @Param("widgets") List widgets);
}
```

Test code:

```
List<Widget> updates = new ArrayList<>();
updates.add(all.get(0));
updates.add(all.get(2));

repository.setStatus("status B", updates);
```

It should do all the updates in a single transaction.